# Expression<Func<T, bool>>, having trouble with the Repository pattern and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, repository-pattern

I've recently jumped in the Repository pattern while using Entity Framework. I wrote a basic CRUD interface that I implemented for each entity that I had. I also wanted to go further by using Expression> but there's a little problem. Enougth talk, let's show code.

Here's my User entity :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the method that annoy me a lot :

```
public async Task<User> FindOne(Expression<Func<User, bool>> wheres)
{
    using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
    {
        User user = await context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(wheres);
        return user;
    }
}
```

And here's how I call it :

```
// user.Username is set by the user via a form
User findOne = await _usersRepository.FindOne(u => u.Username == user.Username);
```

**The problem is** that I have a **null value** in my variable and I'm sure that I have one record that matches my condition !

Here is a copy/paste of the "wheres" value when I step into the FindOne function :

```
{u => (u.Username == value(MyApi.Controllers.UsersController+<>c__DisplayClass1e).username)}
```

In fact, I dunno how to debug that...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the sync variant? Maybe it could be the great start for debug, to find out if it really works... Looking at it, I cannot find any problem in the code.

Comment: I would start with launching the Sql Profiler and seeing what actual query is executed and whether or not it does return any results.

Comment: @Zoka : no change in the sync way.

Comment: @WiktorZychla : I profiled the SQL, here's the query that cause problem (I replaced the "at" by "[A]") : (Bunch of SELECT...) FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Username] = [A]p__linq__0',N'[A]p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',[A]p__linq__0=N'testuser'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out what was the problem. In fact, the context was not properly initialized (due to a wrong DatabazeInitializer, but there were data in the DB), the code shown above is perfectly working now.